# How to link to a specific framework version in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, version

I've got an application that links against OS X's Python.framework. Since Snow Leopard has upgraded to Python 2.6, the framework now contains versions for 2.4, 2.5, and 2.6. My program doesn't seem to want to link against 2.6, though, and this ends up causing errors when I try and use features from the newer Python runtime.

I know I can just use install_name_tool to change the linking in a post-build step, but is there any way to simply tell it where to link during the build? Seems like a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this, but I believe it will work.

1)  Do NOT add the framework to your Xcode project

2)  Instead, use the full path to the library in "OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS" - so "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/2.5/Python"

3)  You'll also want to set the framework search path to "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/2.5/" and set the include search path to "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/2.5/Headers"

However, with all that said, it will leave you vulnerable to any changes Apple may make.  For example, everything will break if they later remove 2.5 from the framework.  It'd be a much better idea to just update your app to work with the current version of Python.

Comment: Right, I *want* to link to the newer version of Python. The problem is that my program seems to only want to link against the 2.5 version, even with the include and lib paths set. I can fix it after the fact, but that feels like a kludge.

Comment: This suggestion worked for linking to an older framework (for example, if you link to Python.framework on 10.7, the app won't load on 10.6 (even though this is otherwise a valid method for building a binary that knows how to detect and use functions from 10.7 and 10.6 through weak linking).   However, in Xcode 4, I manually specified the library in the link phase and it worked fine (as opposed to doing it with OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS)

Answer (score 1):

I had this specific problem, too, and couldnt find a way to get Python Framework 2.6 in the build.

I couldn't get the OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS approach to work, alas.

So, like SJML suggested, I used a post build step like so:

```
#
# Force the required version of Python to be 2.6
# dvb10.12.01

install_name_tool \
    -change \
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Python \
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python \
    $TARGET_BUILD_DIR/omino_python.plugin/Contents/MacOS/omino_python
```

Just putting it out there for the grepping. :)