# How to use AFNetworking 2.0 in iOS5?

Tags: ios, ios5, afnetworking

I am working on a project based on iOS5. I want to use AFNetworking 2.0 by cocoapods. But 'iOS6+' is needed. Can I use AFNetworking 1.x when it's iOS5 while using 2.0 when it's iOS6+ ?

thanks

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414807/how-to-link-to-a-specific-framework-version-in-xcode as this question is also asking about using different versions of frameworks. Though I have to ask why not just use `AFNetworking 1.x` or drop support for iOS 5 as there aren't that many people left on it now.

Comment: You should think why your App still need to support iOS 5 if your App is not as same as Alipay, Wechat, etc. .

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to use AFNetworking 2.0 with iOS 5
source: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#requirements

Its not worth targeting iOS 5 anymore. I don't even target iOS 6 anymore. There's just too much compatibility code you have to write to get it working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods does not support it directly and it is not recommended.

Check [Link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2349).